# How can I use ag-grid new property rowGroupExpandState Type 'expanded' | 'collapsed' | 'match' Default expanded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, aggregation-framework

I m trying to use Ag-Grid v30 new feature ( rowGroupExpandState Type 'expanded' | 'collapsed' | 'match' Default expanded )In nested ag grid data table. below you can find the url
Docs: https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/excel-export-api/

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/excel-export-master-detail/

I am trying to export the data based on 'expanded' | 'collapsed' | 'match' Expanded is working fine because it is  default rest collspsed and match not working

I tried to some code

```
var getRows = (params) => {
  const rows = [
    {
      outlineLevel: 1,
      cells: [
        cell(''),
        cell('Call Id', 'header'),
        cell('Direction', 'header'),
        cell('Number', 'header'),
        cell('Duration', 'header'),
        cell('Switch Code', 'header'),
      ],
    },
  ].concat(
    ...params.node.data.callRecords.map((record) => [
      {
        outlineLevel: 1,
        cells: [
          cell(''),
          cell(record.callId, 'body'),
          cell(record.direction, 'body'),
          cell(record.number, 'body'),
          cell(record.duration, 'body'),
          cell(record.switchCode, 'body'),
        ],
      },
    ])
  );
  return rows;
};

var defaultCsvExportParams = {
  getCustomContentBelowRow: (params) => {
    const rows = getRows(params);

    return rows.map((row) => row.cells);
  },
};
var defaultExcelExportParams = {
  getCustomContentBelowRow: (params) => getRows(params),
  columnWidth: 120,
  fileName: 'ag-grid.xlsx',
};

/** @type {import('ag-grid-community').GridOptions} */
const gridOptions = {
  columnDefs: [
    // group cell renderer needed for expand / collapse icons
    { field: 'name', cellRenderer: 'agGroupCellRenderer' },
    { field: 'account' },
    { field: 'calls' },
    { field: 'minutes', valueFormatter: "x.toLocaleString() + 'm'" },
  ],
  defaultColDef: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  masterDetail: true,
  detailCellRendererParams: {
    detailGridOptions: {
      columnDefs: [
        { field: 'callId' },
        { field: 'direction' },
        { field: 'number', minWidth: 150 },
        { field: 'duration', valueFormatter: "x.toLocaleString() + 's'" },
        { field: 'switchCode', minWidth: 150 },
      ],
      defaultColDef: {
        flex: 1,
      },
    },
    getDetailRowData: (params) => {
      params.successCallback(params.data.callRecords);
    },
  },
  defaultCsvExportParams: defaultCsvExportParams,
  defaultExcelExportParams: defaultExcelExportParams,
  excelStyles: [
    {
      id: 'header',
      interior: {
        color: '#aaaaaa',
        pattern: 'Solid',
      },
    },
    {
      id: 'body',
      interior: {
        color: '#dddddd',
        pattern: 'Solid',
      },
    },
  ],
};

function cell(text, styleId) {
  return {
    styleId: styleId,
    data: {
      type: /^\d+$/.test(text) ? 'Number' : 'String',
      value: String(text),
    },
  };
}

function onBtExport() {
  gridOptions.api.exportDataAsExcel({rowGroupExpandState:{'Nora Thomas': 'collapsed'});
}

// setup the grid after the page has finished loading
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
  new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);

  fetch('https://www.ag-grid.com/example-assets/master-detail-data.json')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      gridOptions.api.setRowData(data);
    });
});
```